# Java wrong value initialization

Tags: java, initialization

I have training object programming and I stucked at testing.
My programm scan pet info and print it at screen(basic of basics).
When I enter pet info:

```
name - Jimbo (min 3 max 16 letters)
type - 2 ( dog)
gender - 1 (male)
```

I got this output:

```
Pet info:
Your pet name is Jimbo, pet type is dog, and gender is male.
```

it write everything normaly, but when I enter this:

```
name - Ji
type - 8 (out of choices)
gender - 8 (out of choices)
```

i got this output:

```
Pet info:
Your pet name is ji, pet type is unknown type, and gender is unknown gender.
```

Instead of `ji` i should get words `"wrong name length"` but it still prints `ji`.
Im confused. I have started java  object programming and want to understand it fully.

Main.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner key_scan = new Scanner (System.in); 


        System.out.println("Enter your pet name(min 3 letters, max 16 letters): ");// select your pet name
        String pet_name = key_scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your pet type number 1(cat), 2(dog), 3(mouse), 4(fish): ");// select your pet type
        int pet_type = key_scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter your pet gender 1(male), 2(female): ");// select your pet gender
        int pet_gender = key_scan.nextInt();

        petInfo obj_petInfo = new petInfo(pet_name, pet_type, pet_gender);

        System.out.printf("Pet info:\n%s", obj_petInfo.formatPetInfo());

        key_scan.close(); // close scanner key_scan
    }
}
```

petInfo.java

```
public class petInfo {
    private String pet_name;
    private int pet_type;
    private int pet_gender;

    public petInfo(){
        this("Unknown", 0, 0);  
    }

    public petInfo(String pet_name_t, int pet_type_t, int pet_gender_t){
        pet_name = pet_name_t;// string name
        pet_type = pet_type_t;// int type
        pet_gender = pet_gender_t;// int gender
    }
////////////////////////////////set methods 
    public void setPet_name(String pet_name){
        pet_name = ((pet_name.length() >= 3 && pet_name.length() <= 16)? pet_name : "wrong name length");
    }
///////////////////////////////// pet type  
    public void makePet_type_cat(int pet_type){
        pet_type = 1;
    }

    public void makePet_type_dog(int pet_type){
        pet_type = 2;
    }

    public void makePet_type_mouse(int pet_type){
        pet_type = 3;
    }

    public void makePet_type_fish(int pet_type){
        pet_type = 4;
    }
////////////////////////////// pet gender   
    public void makePet_gender_male(int pet_gender){
        pet_gender = 1;
    }

    public void makePet_gender_female(int pet_gender){
        pet_gender = 2;
    }

    boolean pet_is_male(){
        return this.pet_gender == 1;
    }

    boolean pet_is_female(){
        return this.pet_gender == 2;
    }

//////////////////////////////// pet type check
    boolean pet_is_cat(){
        return this.pet_type == 1;
    }

    boolean pet_is_dog(){
        return this.pet_type == 2;
    }

    boolean pet_is_mouse(){
        return this.pet_type == 3;
    }

    boolean pet_is_fish(){
        return this.pet_type == 4;
    }
/////////////////////////////////////get methods
    public String getPet_name(){
        return pet_name;
    }

    String getPet_type(){
    if (this.pet_is_cat())
            return "cat";
        else if(this.pet_is_dog())
            return "dog";
        else if(this.pet_is_mouse())
            return "mouse";
        else if(this.pet_is_fish())
            return "fish";
        else
            return "unknown type";  
    }   

    String getPet_gender(){
        if(this.pet_is_male())
            return "male";
        else if (this.pet_is_female())
            return "female";
        return "unknown gender";
    }

    String formatPetInfo(){
        return String.format("Your pet name is %s, pet type is %s, and gender is %s.", getPet_name(), this.getPet_type(), this.getPet_gender());
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related but please [read Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Also your code is very bad OOP. You might like looking at [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) and [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Comment: And enums, for that matter. This is a great example project.

Comment: @m0skit0 thanks for ur advice about Naming conventions, now im changing all methods, variables names, I will try to write corectly for now on :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that although `setPetName` does validation of the name, the constructor performs a "straight" assignment without validation.

Change the constructor as follows:

```
public petInfo(String pet_name_t, int pet_type_t, int pet_gender_t){
    setPet_name(pet_name_t);// string name
    pet_type = pet_type_t;// int type
    pet_gender = pet_gender_t;// int gender
}
```

This will fix the problem.

Note that your code goes against Java naming conventions: rather than calling the setter method `setPet_name`, naming conventions suggest `setPetName`. Following naming conventions is very important to ensure code readability, so other method names should be changed in a similar way.

Answer (score 2):

You have not called your setPet_name, anywhere which will basically do the validation.  The values of name is assigned through the following constructor call:

```
    petInfo obj_petInfo = new petInfo(pet_name, pet_type, pet_gender);
```

which calls the below constructor and assigns the name without any validation:

```
public petInfo(String pet_name_t, int pet_type_t, int pet_gender_t){
    pet_name = pet_name_t;// string name
    pet_type = pet_type_t;// int type
    pet_gender = pet_gender_t;// int gender
}
```

You can call your setter in the constructor to assign the values instead of direct assignment:

```
public petInfo(String pet_name_t, int pet_type_t, int pet_gender_t){
    setPet_name(pet_name_t);// string name
    pet_type = pet_type_t;// int type
    pet_gender = pet_gender_t;// int gender
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, changed constructor and now its working :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your conventions that is still possible, Java has a keyword `this` that refers to current object so you may use `this` like:

```
public petInfo(String pet_name_t, int pet_type_t, int pet_gender_t){
    this.pet_name = pet_name_t;// pet_name_t refers to local variable get from parameterlist but this.pet_name_t refers to global variable of class what you defined as "private String pet_name;"
    this.pet_type = pet_type_t;// int type
    this.pet_gender = pet_gender_t;// int gender
}
```